# Returning the X+1 item in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indexing

So far I have a function that creates gray code then I need to make a function that will return the gray code "plus one", basically the next in sequence. so if D = (0,0,1,1) I need to return (0,0,1,0)

I have

```
def gray(x):
    if x:
        return ['0' + x[0]] + gray(x[1:]) + ['1' + x[0]]
    else:
        return []

def graycode(n):
    if n:
        return gray(graycode(n-1))
    else:
        return ['']
```

then lastly,

```
def GrayFinal(D):
    z = ''.join(map(str,D))
    str(z)
    if z in graycode(len(D)):
        return graycode(len(D))[z+1]
    else:
        return ['']
```

I can't figure out how to return the Zth+1 entry

Comment: Might be an idea to make sure your indentation is correctly represented in the post... it didn't survive a copy/paste very well...

Comment: Yes I noticed that, thank you for the fix!

Comment: do you mean "how to increment graycodes by 1"?

Comment: I found this on Google. Does this work for you? http://www.barricane.com/python-grey-code-algorithm.html

Comment: Yes, the first two functions I just tried to get the desired n-bits then the last one I wanted to return the next increment of the gray code. so GrayFinal((0,0,1,1)) I want to return (0,0,1,0).

Comment: This has a class for all you need if you do not want to do it yourself: http://pythonhosted.org/sympy/modules/combinatorics/graycode.html

Comment: The point is I'm trying to do myself. graycode(len(D)) returns an n-bit. I want to search for z in this list, then return the next increment. Is there a correct way to use indexing in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpreted your question correctly, the heart of your question really has nothing to do with Gray codes, but rather with the more general question, "*Given an element I wish to find in a Python list, how do I retrieve the next element after that?*"

Unfortunately I can only come up with a rather brain-dead solution right now which is

```
def next_elem(elem, input_list):
    index = input_list.index(elem)
    return input_list[index + 1]
```

Note that this has absolutely no support whatsoever for error checking, which I assume in your case would be done in the body of the code. Throwing that into your code would result in the following:

```
def GrayFinal(D):
    z = ''.join(map(str,D))
    try:
        return next_elem(z, graycode(len(D)))
    except ValueError:
        # Doesn't look like z was ever in the Gray code generated
        return ['']
    except IndexError:
        # The next element is beyond the last element of the array!
        return next_elem('0' + z, graycode(len(D) + 1))
```

Comment: Ah, yes the element is beyond the last element of the array. Still trips me up when I'm writing functions. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Eh... I forgot to actually do anything in the case of IndexError. That's been fixed now. I'm still trying to think if there's a prettier way of doing this.

Comment: I extremely appreciate the help. I'm trying deleting the if statement and I don't think I even need "str(z)"

Comment: BTW, I know your question was specific to your implementation, but on the off-chance you're looking to improve the algorithm itself, I think ultimately something similar what @User suggested is best (i.e. the Gray to binary, increment, then convert back to Gray). It gets rid of the need to generate all the Gray codes that have the same number of digits as the one in question.

Answer (score 0):

Here something I heard about:

```
>>> bin2gray = lambda x: (x >> 1) ^ x # create graycode
>>> for i in range(10):
    print(bin(bin2gray(i))[2:].zfill(4))


0000
0001
0011
0010
0110
0111
0101
0100
1100
1101

>>> def gray2bin(g):
    bits = list(map(int, bin(g)[2:]))
    n = [0]
    for bit in bits:
        if not n[-1]:
            n.append(bit)
        else:
            n.append(1 - bit)
    return sum([n[i] << (-1 - i) for i in range(-len(n), 0)])

>>> def inc(g):
    return bin2gray(gray2bin(g) + 1)
```

You will need to adapt the inc function if you want it to work with strings instead of ints.